# Scrolling in Gnucash

Tags: gnucash, macos

Scrolling in a Gnucash register seems extremely touchy - the slightest touch on my touchpad (I have a MacBook Pro) scrolls a whole screen of transactions.

Is there any way to adjust the sensitivity?  I'm happy with the scrolling speed in other apps on this machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a program, not finance.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can ask the Gnucash team in a more appropriate forum.  Thanks.